# changing page/url within an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a php file with the iframe below...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<iframe src="/test.php?id=1" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; height:100%; width:100%; border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

In test.php, after a button is clicked, I am trying to get the page to change to verified.php but without changing the parent url or trying to change the iframe src.

Anyone have any ideas? I was trying to open another iframe in test.php but I couldn't see it because the original iframe was still there.

Comment: You question is terse. For instance what do you mean by `I am trying to get the page to change to verified.php` ?

Comment: In iFrame, links are followed. Have you tested something ? what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.top` when inside an iFrame

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp

> When the "Check window" button is clicked, the function check() is called and the current window status is checked. If the topmost window (window.top) is different from the current window (window.self), then output that "This window is not the topmost window! Am I in a frame?". If the topmost window equals the current window, then fire the else statement:

So to redirect the "parent" page from within the iFrame:

```
window.top.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

### UPDATE

I don't get this, but you can replace it.

> [without] trying to change the iframe src

If you just want to replace it the easiest way is to clone, change the `src` in the clone then replaceWith the clone.

I cant really use iFrames on SO, but I can show the concept using a simple `p` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var clone = $('p').clone();   
    clone.html("hello");   
    $('p').replaceWith(clone);

    console.log('contains "hello" instead of test, which proves we\'ve replaced it.');
    console.log('cloning retains the red color style');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color:red;" >Test</p>
```

Instead of that you would just do

```
var clone = $('iframe').clone();   
clone.attr("src", "otherPage.html");   
$('iframe').replaceWith(clone);
```

And if you don't want to change the `src` on the clone, then just hard code the iFrame

```
$('iframe').replaceWith('<iframe src="otherPage" {styles} ></iframe>);
```

Cloning is a bit nicer because then you don't lose any of the styles or attributes that are applied to the iframe.

**But**  To be honest without more from you on what you are currently doing and what you want to do, no one can answer this unless they are mind readers.

Comment: I don't want to change the parent url, just within the iframe.

Comment: NM, I see you don't want to change the src. You would want to replace it then?

Comment: Yes, the iframe is going to a php file and I have a script that will determine what to do after the button is clicked. I want to then load /verified.php, within the iframe, so nothing on the parent side changes...

Comment: `Everything i've tried` whats that.  I need to see way more code `Yes, the iframe is going to a php file and I have a script that will determine what to do after the button is clicked.` to help you.

Comment: how does the `iframe` go to the PHP page, is it just the `src` or are you targeting it with a form submission.  What button, where is it ( parent or iframe ). what kind of script, javascript, or php. etc.. I need to know what you are doing.

Comment: The fix depends on in what context you are working, are you inside the iframe, does the button submit something? If so, does it submit the parent page, or the iframe.  Is this all "client side"?  etc. etc..